# Not enough memory

Tags: c, pointers

For some reason when I insert n=99999999, I dont get the message "Not enough memory".
The program stops running and I get the following error:

```
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 6.449 s
```

Why is this happening?

```
int i, j;
int **a=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
if (**a==NULL){
    printf("Not enough memory\n");
    return 1;
}
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
     a[i]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    if (**a==NULL){
        printf("Not enough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The test `if (**a==NULL){` should be `if (a==NULL){` and next one should be `if (a[i]==NULL){`.

Comment: Instead of an array of pointers to arrays it's often more efficient to allocate a singular one-dimensional array and emulate the two dimensional aspect using offset calculations. It's also a good idea to wrap up these allocations inside of functions that can neatly allocate or free structures of this sort.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
if (a==NULL){
    printf("Not enough memory\n");
    return 1;
}
```

instead of

```
if (**a==NULL){
    printf("Not enough memory\n");
    return 1;
}
```

because `malloc()` returns a pointer to the allocated memory if it was successful which is assigned to `a` (not `**a` or `*a`).

Also there's no need to cast the return value of `malloc()`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) post.

And as [P.P.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1275169/p-p) pointed out, it's

```
a[i]=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
if (a[i]==NULL){
     printf("Not enough memory\n");
     return 1;
}
```

and not

```
a[i]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
if (**a==NULL){
     printf("Not enough memory\n");
     return 1;
}
```

Edit: Note that the return value of `malloc()` needn't be explicitly cast in C. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/5375464) post.